# Problem with creating online user list with socket.io and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to add a list of online users to my chat app, but I ran into this problem:

On the front end I emit the currently logged in user's name, and then update the state of my users  array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
      const { data } = Auth.getUserInfo();
      socket.emit("user_connected", data.username);
    }
// if I remove these brackets I get an infinite loop in my server
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("online_users", (onlineUsers) => {
      setUsers(onlineUsers);
      console.log(users);
    });
  });
```

I created the user array in the back end using the emitted username:

```
const onlineUsers = [];
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.join("public_chat");
  console.log(`A user has joined the chat`);

  socket.on("user_connected", (user) => {
    const userExists = checkUserArray(user, onlineUsers);
    if (!userExists) {
      onlineUsers.push({ user, id: socket.id });
    }
    console.log(onlineUsers);
    socket.in("public_chat").emit("online_users", onlineUsers);

    console.log(`${user} is now online.`);
  });
});
```

I opened two separate browsers with two different logged in users to test, and when I refresh the page on one browser, the other gets the updated online user list in real-time, but the browser I initially refreshed on has an empty array for the user state. Do I need to make a global state store using redux or something?

Comment: Send the list to the new user when they connect for the first time.

Comment: @ggorlen I added `socket.emit("online_users", onlineUsers)` to the actual io.on connection which got it to update the list halfway on one browser and fully on the other, so I put another `socket.emit("online_users", onlineUsers)` in the socket.on user_connected and now its working exactly how I need it to. Appreciate the help but don't really know why that worked hah